# Is there any difference between "that is it" and "that is what it is" in the sense of it is a fact?

Tags: difference, phrases

Is there any difference between the phrases in the following context.

> I couldn't pass the exam. **That's what it is**.
>
> I couldn't pass the exam. **That's it**.

What I am trying to say that I didn't pass exam and that is a fact. Nothing can be changed about it.

Answer (score 1):

Either phrase will work and generally get your meaning across. There is not any real difference in the meaning.

That said, I think maybe the phrase you are looking for is "it is what it is".

> I couldn't pass the exam. It is what it is.

That is a colloquial way of relating that "nothing can be changed about it" (whatever *it* is). You can use the phrase as an informal way of conveying acceptance about some unfortunate thing that has happened.